# SQL dynamic structure

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following structure

```
construction
id
1

building-step
id construction_id  step_id     worker_id
1  1                1           1
1  1                2           2

step
id name
1  foundation
2  wall
3  roof
```

When a new construction is added using a template, building-steps are generated. After the initial configuration steps can be added or removed.

One of the requirements is to display the construction template as a string. The template is dynamic because you can add and remove steps.
In this case the template name is "foundation+wall". If I add another building-step the template name will be "foundation+wall+roof".

My question is, how can this be done in optimized way? 
Is the SQL structure the problem for this dynamic complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres specifically you can use the `string_agg` function, which concats rows of strings.

In you example, you could try:

```
select string_agg(nm,'+') from(
    select st.name as nm
    from building-step bs
    inner join 
    step st
    on bs.step_id=st.id
    where bs.construction_id=1
    order by bs ASC
); --done by hand, may have small errors
```

It will support edits in both tables anytime, and will perform nicely.

Comment: The code is correct but is the sql structure optimal for the requirements?

Comment: Yes, it is good. You should all id columns primary keys if they aren't already, and add an index to building_step(construction_id) that will aid in the where part of the query.
Unless you happen to run this query 1000s of times a day on tables with large rowcount, it will work fine.